# React Native: Child ListView will not update after element in parent is changed

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, react-native, redux

I can't seem to get my `ListView` to update.

I have a parent container with a toggle switch (`<SegmentedControls />`). When the user clicks that toggle switch I'd like the `ListView` in the child component to update using the updated `reservationListSelectedOption` state value.

What am I missing?

Code here: https://gist.github.com/chapeljuice/69483ab0bde13346de024d4e4a9753f0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a solution, thanks to both [thinhvo0108](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7318933/thinhvo0108) and [Matt Aft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5442308/matt-aft) for helping me get there.

Here is my revised `componentWillReceiveProps` function, which combined with fixed dataSource is now updating the ListView correctly:

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  if ( nextProps.reservationListStatus === "Past Reservations" ) {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(reservationData.previous)
    })
  } else {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(reservationData.current)
    })
  }
  console.log( 'nextProps.reservationListStatus: ' + nextProps.reservationListStatus );
}
```

I updated my gist as well with the working code: https://gist.github.com/chapeljuice/69483ab0bde13346de024d4e4a9753f0

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's something wrong in the way you set your `dataSource`, in your constructor, you set it for the first time with: `new ListView.DataSource({})` (this should not be changed later, because this is just kind of dummy thing, no data passed to it yet)

However, later you reset that state with : `dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(reservationData.previous)`

=> (Here it has the `cloneWithRows`, so it will have data now => which means the `this.state.dataSource` "dummy-frame" itself has been changed, and the next execution of `.cloneWithRows` will **fail** - will not have the `.cloneWithRows` function anymore)

======> **SOLUTION:**

In my opinion, you can do:

In **cardList.js**:

```
// Put the data-source ds here, which won't be changed
var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2});

class CardList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      reservationListStatus: this.props.reservationListStatus,
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(/* PUT YOUR INITIAL reservationData, OR JUST a blank array '[]' will be fine*/),
    };
  }
```

..and later on, you just need to use `ds.cloneWithRows(YOUR_NEW_RESERVATION_DATA)` (always keep the `ds` unchanged), something like this:

```
  getReservationData() {
    if ( this.props.reservationListStatus === "Previous Reservations" ) {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(reservationData.previous)
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(reservationData.current)
      })
    }
    console.log(this.state)
  }
```

That is the way you should do, but if it doesn't work yet, please post here some errors you encounter, thanks

Comment: That does make more sense to me so I did switch out my code (and updated my gist in the original question), however my ListView is still not updating. I have that console.log in there that outputs `this.state.reservationListStatus` and no matter which tab option I press the console always outputs "Current Reservations", and never outputs "Previous Reservations".

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `componentWillReceiveProps` to your child component. It would look something like this:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.options !== nextProps.options) {
      this.setState({ reservationListSelectedOption: nextProps.options[0] });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hrm, thanks but that didn't seem to do anything (that I could tell). I'd also want to make sure the state was set dynamically and not use a static option like you have. I'll look into `componentWillReceiveProps` though!